# Javascript form validation radio and check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, validation

OK I have a new problem with my JS form validation project.

I can't get the radio and checkboxes to validate and throw up error messages.

I have a external .js script with function rules linked in my html within the head section.

The function rules look like this:

```
    /* ======================================================================
FUNCTION:   IsValid4DigitZip

INPUT:      str (string) - a 5-digit zip code to be tested

RETURN:     true, if the string is 5-digits long
        false, otherwise

CALLS:  IsBlank(), IsInt() which are defined elsewhere in the Script Library

PLATFORMS:  Netscape Navigator 3.01 and higher,
            Microsoft Internet Explorer 3.02 and higher,
            Netscape Enterprise Server 3.0,
            Microsoft IIS/ASP 3.0.
====================================================================== */
function IsValid4DigitZip( str ) {
    // Return immediately if an invalid value was passed in
    if (str+"" == "undefined" || str+"" == "null" || str+"" == "")  
        return false;

    var isValid = true;

    str += "";

    // Rules: zipstr must be 5 characters long, and can only contain numbers from
   // 0 through 9
   if (IsBlank(str) || (str.length != 4) || !IsInt(str, false))
        isValid = false;

   return isValid;
} // end IsValid4DigitZip
```

How would I add function rules to my external .js script to validate the radio and checkbox forms in my html. Can someone guide me on how to write the function rules?

And how would I call these rules for radio and checkboxes in the  section?

Comment: The function name & the code are for 4 digits, while the comments mention 5 digits - quite a mess. Also the way it's written & the intro comment make it look like a 10+ year old function...

Comment: That was just an example of a validation function rule I have in the external .js script. I would like to know how to write a function rule for my eternal .js script for radio and checkboxes. If that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

validation for `checkbox` and `Radio` button is `Checked function`

In javascript

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById("male").checked || document. 
getElementById("female").checked)
{
  //messages
}
</script>
```

Comment: my form is called "orderbooks" and my checkboxes name is "booksselection1-6" and my radio is named "paymethod1-3." How would I format the code using your script with my details?

Comment: 1:  assign id to each check box and radio buttons,2:  in validation use jQuery code to check any one is checked

Comment: Sorry I'm not using jQuery to validate the html forms. Pure vanilla Javascript only.